# Will the identity column work in bulk insert?

Tags: sql, identity, bulkinsert

I have a table with identity column. While inserting the data into table using bulk insert the identity column is not incrementing. I created the text file like the format of the file without the identity column field. Also I created the format file using the following cmd commands.

**

> bcp  -T -E -c

**

could any one help me in this case? if any  further reference need just give a replay.

Comment: bulk insert emp123 from 
'C:\Documents and Settings\msi1190\Desktop\New Folder\t1.txt'
with(  
formatfile = 'C:\Documents and Settings\msi1190\test\js.fmt'
 )

Comment: Msg 4832, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Bulk load: An unexpected end of file was encountered in the data file.
Msg 7399, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)" reported an error. The provider did not give any information about the error.
Msg 7330, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot fetch a row from OLE DB provider "BULK" for linked server "(null)".

Comment: while executing the above query i am getting this type of error....how can i solve. i think if i am doing the format file without that column then it is inserting. how it is possible.

Comment: Perhaps you should ask a new question describing the trouble you have now. Does not seem to me that this is related to how identity columns is populated with bcp.

Answer (score 1):

Remove -E

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx

> Specifies that identity value or
>   values in the imported data file are
>   to be used for the identity column. If
>   -E is not given, the identity values for this column in the data file being
>   imported are ignored, and SQL Server
>   automatically assigns unique values
>   based on the seed and increment values
>   specified during table creation.

Comment: bulk insert emp123 from 
'C:\Documents and Settings\msi1190\Desktop\New Folder\t1.txt'
with(  
formatfile = 'C:\Documents and Settings\msi1190\test\je.fmt'
 )

Answer (score 1):

Add the identity column to the end of the table. All the columns till the identity column must match with your data file and the table. So make sure there is no data defined in the data file for the identity column.